# C# Excel Interop chart legends displays string format instead of values

Tags: c#, excel, charts, interop

So I'm trying to write a function to convert the printarea of certain worksheets in a workbook to image files.

These worksheets contain a few charts, and on some charts, the image is displaying the legend like this:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILZp1.png)

When i open it in Excel it displays fine. Also worth to mention that i'm using Excel in Hungarian, but some month was displayed in English on other charts when converted into pictures.

The References for the C# Console Application:

```cs
using System;
using xls = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;

public static bool makeimage(string excelpath,string savefolder) {

    bool ret = true;

    string fileNameToProcess = excelpath;            
    xls.Application oExcel = new xls.Application();
    xls.Workbook wb = null;
    try
    {
        wb = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(fileNameToProcess.ToString(), false, true, Type.Missing, "", "", true, xls.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", false, false, 0, false, true, 0);
        wb.RefreshAll();
        xls.Sheets sheets = wb.Worksheets as xls.Sheets;
        for (int i = 1; i <= sheets.Count; i++)
        {
            xls.Worksheet sheet = sheets[i];
            if (sheet.Visible == 0) { continue; }
            xls.Range range = null;
            Console.WriteLine(sheet.Name);
            try
            {                        
                range = sheet.Range[sheet.PageSetup.PrintArea];                     
                sheet.Activate();
                sheet.Calculate();
                sheet.Evaluate(range);
                oExcel.ActiveWindow.View = xls.XlWindowView.xlNormalView;


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                continue;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Converting range to image: " + range.CopyPicture(xls.XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen, xls.XlCopyPictureFormat.xlBitmap).ToString());

            if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
            {
                string imagepath = savefolder + sheet.Name + ".PNG";
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(imagepath))
                    System.IO.File.Delete(imagepath);
                Image imgRange1 = Clipboard.GetImage();
                imgRange1.Save(imagepath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

            }
            sheets[i].Delete();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        ret = false;
        //throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        wb.Close(false);
        oExcel.Quit();
        oExcel = null;
    }
    
    return ret; 
}
```

Same Issue rises when i try to convert these sheets to PDF.

```cs
public static bool makePDF(string excelpath, string savefolder)
{

    bool ret = true;

    string fileNameToProcess = excelpath;
    //Start Excel and create a new document.
    xls.Application oExcel = new xls.Application();
    xls.Workbook wb = null;
    try
    {
        wb = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(fileNameToProcess.ToString(), false, true, Type.Missing, "", "", true, xls.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", false, false, 0, false, true, 0);
        wb.RefreshAll();
        xls.Sheets sheets = wb.Worksheets as xls.Sheets;
        for (int i = 1; i <= sheets.Count; i++)
        {
            xls.Worksheet sheet = sheets[i];
            if (sheet.Visible == 0) { continue; }
            xls.Range range = null;
            Console.Write(sheet.Name);
            try
            {                      
             
                range = sheet.Range[sheet.PageSetup.PrintArea];
                //Console.WriteLine(range.Address.ToString());
                sheet.Activate();
                sheet.Calculate();
                sheet.Evaluate(range);
                oExcel.ActiveWindow.View = xls.XlWindowView.xlNormalView;
                sheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(xls.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, savefolder+sheet.Name, xls.XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard, false, false, 1, 1, false);
                
                Console.WriteLine(" has been converted");
                

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" has not been converted");
                continue;
            }
           

            //}
            sheets[i].Delete();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        ret = false;
        //throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        wb.Close(false);
        oExcel.Quit();
        oExcel = null;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Anybody has any suggestions what am i missing or what could i try?

Answer (score 0):

I did not found out why this happened, but i did manage to tackle the problem by saving the excel document to a different place, then copied each sheets used range, and paste it back as values, and then save the pictures or PDF.